# Django: Expression can be simplified. square brackets

Tags: square, simplify

```
def _by_list(request, names, every_name):
    every_names = request.GET.getlist(every_name, '')
    names_list = map(lambda n: Q(**{names:n}), every_names)
    if names_list == []:  # Expression can be simplified
        return Q(**{names:'_'})
    else:
        return reduce(lambda a, b: a | b, names_list)
```

if i use 'if names_list' it's dosn't work as expected

Comment: Do you mean `if not names_list:` ? Just replacing `names_list == []` with `names_list` inverts the logic.

Comment: in my case names_list can equal to `[]` or `[<Q: (AND: ('n1', u'Client'))>, ...]`, not `None`, so i can't use `if names_list`:. BTW the main question was 'what does it mean # Expression can be simplified?' , now i know i should use `names_list == list()` instead of `names_list == []`

Comment: However, efficiency of using square brackets is obvious: `import timeit`   
  `timeit.timeit('names_list == []', number=10000, setup='names_list = []')`
0.0006949901580810547    `timeit.timeit('names_list == list()', number=10000, setup='names_list = []')`
0.0037691593170166016    `timeit.timeit('names_list == list()', number=10000, setup='names_list = list()')`
0.0033631324768066406